# How do I get an "Empty" for texture coordinates node?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-coordinates

I'm currently working on a voronoi texture, and it looks kinda stretched. I tried looking for a way to unstretch it, and they all said that I need to use a texture coordinate and use an "Empty" as its object. But I tried looking for it and I couldnt find anything. Is there anyone that can help me find the empty, or maybe to unstretch  with another way?
[image]

Comment: And yes, I clicked the object thingy on the texture coordinates node but I can't find an empty.

Comment: You have to add an empty to your scene first (`Shift + A > Empty > Plain Axes`). Easier, however, might be to use "object" texture coordinate, and/or a Mapping node.

Comment: I already did, but it doesn't really change anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure. The base setup should look like the image I linked. If you have the same setup, and the "empty" is not showing in the texture coordinate box, I'm not sure what's wrong. Image is here - https://ibb.co/Zz3yh62